# How to Create Required validation for radio group and check box list and Textbox in uploaded pdf in docusign using c#.net

Tags: c#, docusignapi, required

I am  displaying  pdf file with docusign integration using c#.
Pdf file actually contains no of Radio buttons(Yes or No) and text fields and signature.
I am trying to implement Required field validation for pdf form fields in docusign integration.But I am unable to get solution for this.
Can any body please give the solution how apply the validations for docusign integration pdf form  using c#.net.

Comment: what do you mean by validation? just to ensure fields are filled? or some other logic?

Answer (score 0):

If the textbox tab is required tab - it will be validated, to ensure some text was entered. You can also specify maximum length like this:

```
    Text textTab = new Text();
    textTab.MaxLength = "10";
    textTab.ValidationMessage = "must be at least 10 charchters";
```

As for checkboxes, you can make them checked or unchecked by default. There's no validation because they only have 2 states.
Radio buttons, you can group them together and require that exactly one is selected.

```
    RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup { Radios = new List<Radio>() };
    Radio r1 = new Radio();
    Radio r2 = new Radio();
    rg.Radios.Add(r1);
    rg.Radios.Add(r2);
```